# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagsInput' (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying [this](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)

I imported the `js` and `css` file, and I am certain they are getting loaded into the page.

In the page itself I am using:

```
<script>
$('#findprofiles').tagsInput({
    width: 'auto',
    autocomplete_url:'<?=base_url()?>loadajax/find_people/brandon'
});
</script>
```

against my input

```
<input type="text" id="findprofiles" />
```

but I am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagsInput' (anonymous function)
```

Comment: You didn't include the plugin correctly, or you incorrectly included another version of jquery.

Comment: Try creating a fiddle to test and show it here

Comment: Make sure the script tag including the library is in the markup before your custom code, and make sure your custom code is running at the bottom of the page (or at least below the point at which the input box appears), or, enclose your custom code in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that error because `tagsInput` was not extended in the jQuery object like you expected it to.  Either the tagsInput library wasn't loaded properly by your web browser (check for HTTP errors or JavaScript errors in the console), or the version of jQuery you're using isn't compatible in some way (probably also indicated by errors in the console.)